# Update Lookup Column with Multiple values using Designer Workflow in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, lookup-column

In SP Online using designer workflow,I am trying to update a lookup column(with multiple values enabled) from another lookup column(with multiple values enabled).Both lookup columns are in different lists. I tried different ways but the update is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

From the below thread, I came to know that in SP Online,you cannot update a Lookup column with multiple value using workflow as this a bug. Is this true? Can someone confirm?

https://community.nintex.com/thread/5808

Answer (score 0):

Using a 2010 workflow type and updating the Lookup column in 1;#;#2;#;#3 format resolved the issue.Looks like this is a bug in 2013 workflow type.

**Update:** In SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow,to update a Lookup column, you need to update the ID value of the looked up column,there are no formats to update Lookup column.**Have to check if this works for Multi-select Lookup Column**

In the below example, SOW# is a Lookup column and its updated using the ID column[image]